# OpenCV Hierarchy Cell Segmentation

Tags: opencv, cell, hierarchy, segment

I have seperated two types of cell with Matlab, however I have created all my codes by using OpenCV. With OpenCV I used this code to label my cell with its hole :

```
for( int j = 0; j< contours_cropped.size();  j=hierarchy[j][0]  )
{
    if( hierarchy_cropped[j][2] > 0  )
    {
        putText(src,"RBC",Point(Coord.x,Coord.y), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1,CV_RGB(255,255,255),1);
    }
    else
    {
        putText(src,"WBC",Point(Coord.x,Coord.y), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1,CV_RGB(255,255,255),1);

    }
```

You can see my thresholded and binary image to segment :[Binary Image](http://www.hizliresimyukle.com/images/2014/08/13/Adsz729a0.png)

The left cells are WBC and the code put only WBC so that's right.
So my problem is that the code put WBC and RBC both of them to right side cell. I want to put only RBC at right cells. How can I segment that two types of cell?

Comment: I do not understand: What are the left and the right cells? And what are "WBC" "RBC", because I have found many things ("Royal Bans Council" ... etc)?

Comment: I have added a link including a binary image. At binary image , you can see four windows , so the two at left side are WBC(White Blood Cell) and the two right side are RBC (Right Blood Cell).. The difference between two image is a black hole.

Comment: Have you tried to use `3` instead of `2`, if you see [this](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_hierarchy/py_contours_hierarchy.html), there are some hierarchy 2a and 2b or 3a and 3b... Or maybe `> 1`

Comment: I have read this article but how can I implement to my codes 2a or 2b ?

Answer (score 0):

I see at least more reasons:

- in the RBC case you have more than just 2 contours (and I think it is the same for WBC). I think you shall do check on all the contours in the image, if one has hierarchy > 0 then it is RBC
- `hierarchy_cropped[j][2]` is not always > 0, so you write both RBC and WBC on each image

I think that you shall write only once, and not for each contour (use a bool flag)